# Read multiple json files inserts only 1 value

Tags: php, json

I have a php script which reads a json data and saves to mysql.

I want to perform a cron or something similar which reads different .json data files which i get every 10 seconds and all the new data to be saved to mysql.

**UPDATED CODE:** The below code seems to read the 3 json datas but saving only one record

```
<?php
$dir='/var/www/html/';
$files = scandir($dir);

foreach ($files as $key=>$value)
{ 
$pos = strpos($value, '.json');   
if ($pos === false) {
    //nothing
}
else{
    echo $value; 
    $ext = pathinfo($value, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); 
    if($ext=='json')
    {
        $file = file_get_contents($dir.$value, FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH); 
        echo '<pre>'.$file; 
        $array=json_decode($file,true);
        $arraykey=array_keys($array); 
        echo $file;

        try 
        {
            //echo 'INSERT INTO gmr(version,visitorId,dwellTime,poiId,srId,zoneId,poiProximityConfidence,zoneProximityConfidence,poiPresenceConfidence,zonePresenceConfidence,normalizedTime) VALUES ("' . implode('", "', $array[$arraykey[0]]) . '")'; 
            $count = $dbh->exec('INSERT INTO gmr(version,visitorId,dwellTime,poiId,srId,zoneId,poiProximityConfidence,zoneProximityConfidence,poiPresenceConfidence,zonePresenceConfidence,normalizedTime) VALUES ("' . implode('", "', $array[$arraykey[0]]) . '")' ) or die(print_r($dbh->errorInfo(), true)); 
            echo $count;
            $dbh = null;
            echo 'Success<br />';
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
?>
```

This is inserting only the values from the 1st file, why not other files

Comment: Create an array with file name and do a foreach

Comment: I dont want to specify or hardcode any json file name, it should automatically read all the json files which i add to a folder and it has to read them

Comment: Then you should do [scandir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) and read all the `.json` files in your folder and do it .. You want me to help that ?

Comment: Yes please, i have updated the question as well, the json files will be added every 5 seconds, and it should read based on timestamp

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this

**Step 1 :** Scan the entire folder

```
$dir = "scan/";
$files = scandir($dir);
```

**Step 2 :** Loop through all the files

```
foreach ($files as $key => $value) {
//loop goes here
}
```

**Step 3 :** Check the extgension of the file

```
$ext = pathinfo($value, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if($ext=='json')
```

So, Your coding will be

```
<?php
$dir = "scan/";
$files = scandir($dir);
foreach ($files as $key => $value) {
$pos = strpos($value, '.json');
$ext = pathinfo($value, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if($ext=='json')
    //Your code here
}
}
```

**Update 1 :**

As the OP wants to loop through all the `.json` files and read the contents of it and save it inside the db

```
<?php
$dir = "scan/";
$a = scandir($dir);
foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
    $pos = strpos($value, '.json');
    if ($pos === false) {
        //nothing
    }
    else
    {
        //echo $value;
        $ext = pathinfo($value, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        if($ext=='json')
        {
            $file = file_get_contents($dir.$value, FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
            echo $file;
            //save this to db
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: have updated my answer, with error and also how to manage the different keys in different json file

Comment: Updated the answer, it will loop through all the `.json` inside the folder and read the content of it..

Comment: yes... .json files will be added to my $dir location every 5 seconds, it should pick the latest files and save

Comment: The above code will read all the `.json` file, there is 2 ways to establish 1. You need to save the json's file name that is already readed 2. you need to check the file, which is created just before the 5-10 seconds

Comment: ok wait, im adding the complete code with ur code and i suppose there is no seperate mechanism for dealing with $array['rtVisitInfoOpObjV1']?? right?

Comment: Yeah, okay.. have a try

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138210/discussion-between-sulthan-allaudeen-and-sachin-s).

Answer (score 1):

scan dir, get files and work with them, set this script into cron

```
$dir    = '/tmp';
$files_arr = scandir($dir);
unset($files_arr[0]);  unset($files_arr[1]);//first two is directories
foreach ($files_arr as $file)
 { //do your staff here

   $fo=fopen($file,"r"); 
 }
```

it's been read all files in folders, if you need to be shuare it's a .json files see the answer below